# Cleaner code when using alternative syntax and associative arrays.

Tags: php, foreach

Im writing a `foreach` loop for my view using the alternative syntax, to get a piece of html like this

`<h3><a href="post.php/?id=1">My Post</a></h3>`

Ive used the line below, but it seems awfully clunky with all the concatenation.

```
<?php   
    foreach ($index_posts as $post):
?>

<h3><?= "<a href='post.php/?id='". $post['id'] . ">" . $post['title'] . "</a>"; ?></h3> 

<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```

Ive also tried writing it like this :

`<?= "<a href='post.php/?id=$post['id']'>$post['title']</a>"; ?>`

But it shows errors when written in sublime text 2 around the `['id']` and `['title']` any ideas why this is, as they are single quotes ?

Is there another way i could write this that is cleaner ?

Comment: What's wrong with `<h3><a href='post.php/?id='<?= $post['id'] ?>'><?= $post['title'] ?></a></h3>`? Why have the `<a>` tag go through PHP?

Comment: I consider dedicated templates (pick your flavor and potency) to be a cleaner solution .. I find that code (and markup) cleaner when the rendering and model are separated. (It really doesn't matter what language is being used.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just do:

```
<?php foreach ($index_posts as $post): ?>

<h3>
  <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $post['title']; ?>
  </a>
</h3> 

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: like this version most since it has a border between code and presentation. i m not a fan of echoing html-code in php

Answer (score 2):

The reason Sublime is showing an error when you do this

```
<?= "<a href='post.php/?id=$post['id']'>$post['title']</a>"; ?>
```

is due to the fact that it's a syntax error as you can't have complex variables (like array values with strings for keys) interpolated into a string directly like this.  You need to wrap them in `{}`

```
<?= "<a href='post.php/?id={$post['id']}'>{$post['title']}</a>"; ?>
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    printf('<a href="post.php/?id=%s">%s</a>', $post['id'], $post['title']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach ($index_posts as $post): ?>
    <h3> 
        <a href='post.php/?id=<?=$post['id']?>'>
           <?=$post['title']?>
        </a>
    </h3> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Keeping it to HTML whenever you can; I much prefer to not 'echo' out HTML unless needed, although this question really quite about preference. Afterall, PHP is an *templating* language!

Comment: good point, keep a border between php code and html presentation

Answer (score 0):

Gotta help a fellow sam...

```
<?php echo "<h3><a href=\"post.php?id={$post['id']}\">{$post['title']}</a></h3>"; ?>
```